# Java: Why anonymous inner classes can access methods of outer class?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Lately I've found out that this works, although I'd expect it not to:

```
class Outer
{ 
    Button b;

    void foo() {}


    void bar()
    {
        b = new Button();
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void OnClick()
            {
               foo();
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

I'd expect Outer.this.foo() to be required, but seems that simply foo() also works.
Could someone tell me when exactly this was added to the language? 
Please help me understand exact name resolution rules here. Thanks!

The questions:

1) Why is this working?

2) If this works, why do  we need the "Outer.this" syntax?

Comment: Is this a complaint against the language design?

Comment: No, I just want to understand the exact name resolution rules here.

Comment: I don't find your question very useful. Also asking for off site resources is off-topic.

Comment: If your comment is your actual question, that changes a lot.

Comment: I believe inner classes were added back in Java 1.1, which is about in 1997...

Comment: Do you mean that inner classes always have been able to access outer classes's methods even without the "Outer.this" qualification? Why do we need Outer.this then?

Comment: Could people who downvote question explain why they do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibility to call methods like this has existed since the inner classes had been introduced. The mechanism for resolving the instance that a method is called on is described in detail in [Java Language Specification, Section 15.12.4.1., Compute Target Reference (If Necessary)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.1).

You are probably refering to the fact that you don't need the ["Qualified `this`"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4). But this `this` is mainly intended to resolve ambiguities when the inner instance and the outer instance have a method with the same signature.